# Meteor build takes long time after I save my javascript file

Tags: meteor

After I save my javascript file meteor will rebuild app but it takes so long time (I have to wait for 15 minute or more)

Are there solutions to solve it. 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It shouldn't take more than a few seconds for the change detection to work. Are you working on a network drive? Is your machine short of memory, or busy processing something else?

Comment: Also are you on Windows? If so, have you excluded meteor from Windows Defender and from indexing in your code editor?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my personal experience,

1. In general case, when you quit building in between there might be some folders undeleted like below images.

[image]

In such case, delete such folders first.

2. If you are using Windows, RAM can be issue. If you machine has very little memory allocated then building the ever growing Meteor project become very annoying. I came to know this when I upgraded my machine from **1st generation core i5-6GB DDR2 RAM-500GB HDD** to **2nd generation core i7-8GB DDR3 RAM- 248GB SSD** storage drive. Machine configuration plays a vital role for Meteor building for *development env* and *production env*. Earlier configuration took 6 min to build but new configuration took less than a minute for me now.
3. If you have any antivirus software running behind the scene then it too might cause the slow speed for meteor build process.